# USB keyboard is disconecting automatically (without being unplugged)

Tags: kernel, usb, acpi, grsecurity

In my log, I see following message:

```
kernel: usb 1-1.6: USB disconnect, device number 5
acpid:  input device has been disconnected, fd 7
acpid:  input device has been disconnected, fd 8
```

I have not unplugged my USB keyboard, nor any other USB device. Why then, is the USB disconnecting automatically?

The reason why it bothers me is, I am using `grsecurity` with `deny_new_usb` enabled. Once USB device is "unplugged", it cannot be plugged in again. And this is exacly what I see in my log. The next line after the 3 lines mentioned above is:

```
kernel: grsec: denied insert of new USB device
```

As I said, I have not touched the USB cable. Apparently the USB keyboard automatically disconnects/reconnects. But the reconnect is denied and I end up with no keyboard, leaving me the only option to reset my PC with the button.

**Why is this happening?**

**Is there any way to prevent this?**

**IS this some bug in the USB keyboard, or is it kernel issue ?**